# Need help implementing en passant Pawn capture and promotion

Tags: java, chess

I am working on a chessgame and have been able to make my Pawn piece move both one and two squares forward and preventing it from moving two squares forward after its first move. In addition, the Pawn Piece is able to capture piece diagonally but doesn't perform enpassant capture and pawn promotion. For pawn promotion, i need an idea on how to swap the pawn piece with another piece when its targetRow == 0 or 7. Please i will be grateful if someone can help me with a logic or idea on how to implement these two features.

Here is my code:

```
    private boolean isValidPawnMove(int sourceRow, int sourceColumn, int targetRow, int   
    targetColumn){

    boolean isValid = false;

    if(isTargetLocationFree()){

        if(sourceColumn == targetColumn){
            //same column
            if(sourcePiece.getColor() == Piece.YELLOW_COLOR){
                //yellow
                if(sourceRow + 1 == targetRow ){
                    //move one up
                    isValid = true;

                }else if(sourceRow == 1 && targetRow == 3){
                    if(sourceRow + 2 == targetRow) {
                    isValid = true;
                    }                   
                }else{
                    //not moving one up
                    isValid = false;
                }

            }else{
                //brown
                if(sourceRow - 1 == targetRow){
                    //move one down
                    isValid = true;

                }else if(sourceRow == 6 && targetRow == 4){
                    if(sourceRow - 2 == targetRow) {
                       isValid = true;
                    }
                }else{
                    //not moving one down
                    isValid = false;
                }                   
            }
        }else{
            //not the same column
            isValid = false;
        }
    }else if(isTargetLocationCaptureable()){

        if(sourceColumn + 1 == targetColumn || sourceColumn - 1 == targetColumn ){
            //one column to the right or left
            if(sourcePiece.getColor() == Piece.YELLOW_COLOR){
                //yellow
                if(sourceRow + 1 == targetRow){
                    //move one up
                    isValid = true;
                }else{

                    //not moving one up
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }else{
                //brown
                if(sourceRow - 1 == targetRow ){
                    //move one down
                    isValid = true;
                }else{
                    //not moving one down                       
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            //One column to the left or right
            isValid = false;
        }   
    }

        return isValid;
}

private boolean isTargetLocationCaptureable(){
if(targetPiece == null){
    return false;
}else if( targetPiece.getColor() != sourcePiece.getColor()){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}

private boolean isTargetLocationFree(){
return targetPiece == null;
}
```

Comment: How do `isTargetLocationFree` and `isTargetLocationCaptureable` work without any arguments?  Also, I don't see how the above code does anything with the captured piece if you capture it--shouldn't it be doing something to get that piece off the board?

Comment: @ajb, i have updated my code with the **isTargetLocationFree** and **isTargetLocationCaptureable** methods

Comment: I haven't even heard about the `enpassant capture` rule until I Googled it just now. +1 for teaching me something new :)

Comment: really, anyway is not used always :)

Comment: Yikes, this code is pretty confusing.  It looks like sometime before you call this method, you've set `targetPiece` to be the piece at the place where your "source piece" is moving to.  That's not good enough, because for "en passant" you will need to know what piece is at a place one square away from where you're moving to.  I'd get rid of `targetPiece` and define a function `pieceAt(row,column)` to return a piece.  Also, "en passant" is legal only if the other piece is a pawn that *just* moved up two squares, so you'll need a way to determine whether that's the case.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of Chess moves whose validation requires more that the current board state. In your case I'm not seeing the additional information needed to validate the following moves.

- Castling: requires history of involved rook and king. Can be accomplished via a hasMovedBefore flag.
- en Passant: Knowledge of the last move taken. Can be accommodated by retaining a lastMove data structure, or retaining the previous board state.
- Fifty move rule: requires history of when the last capture or pawn move. Can be accomplished via a lastPawnMoveOrCapture counter
- Threefold repetition: requires all previous board states since the last castle, pawn move or capture. A list of hashes of previous states may be an option. (Thanks dfeuer)

Comment: The repeated states rule only needs to hold states since the last capture, castle, or pawn move.

Answer (score 0):

The moving into the last/first row still needs to be a valid move, so I would handle this part right before "return isValid;".  That way you can make use of the isValid boolean.

```
if(isValid && sourcePiece.getColor()==Piece.YELLOW_COLOR && targetRow==0){
//change targetRow,targetColumn to a queen or Piece.Type = "Queen" or however you have it setup
}
```

I don't think you need to actually "swap" the piece with a captured piece in the rules of chess.  You can have two queens on the board.  The only other piece a player could possibly want (rare) is a rook.  I don't having the player choose would be worth your time.

Comment: See http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/730/why-would-one-promote-a-pawn-to-a-knight.

Comment: Thanks!  I wrote rook but I meant a knight.  Maybe the player should be prompted to see if they want a queen or a knight.

Answer (score 0):

The 'en passant' capture is a bit tricky, you must keep track of previous opponent move, and if and only if an opponent pawn just moved by 2 squares and now has column = your pawn column + or - 1, and row = your pawn row, then the move to opponent row column and row + 1 (or -1 for blacks) is allowed, it will capture the opponent pawn. You don't need to check the destination square is empty, as the opponent pawn just moved 2 squares, it is.
Promotion is straightforward, if new row is 0 or 7 then the pawn must become a piece, you just need a user interface for the player to choose, but your algorithm already returns these noves as valid.
For your existing code, it might be a bit easier to read like this:

```
private boolean isValidPawnMove(int sourceRow, int sourceColumn, 
                                int targetRow, int targetColumn) {
    int startRow;
    int direction;
    if (sourcePiece.getColor() == Piece.YELLOW_COLOR) {
      startRow = 1;
      directon = 1;
    } else {
      startRow = 6;
      directon = -1;
    }
    if (isTargetLocationFree() && sourceColumn == targetColumn) {
      return (targetRow == sourceRow + direction) ||
             (sourceRow == startRow && targetRow == startRow + 2 * direction);
    }
    if (isTargetLocationCaptureable()) {
      return ((targetColumn == sourceColumn + 1 || targetColumn == sourceColumn - 1 ))
              && (targetRow == sourceRow + direction);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: I assume all the input variables are already valid and you don't have corner cases such as targetColumn = -1.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for enpassant capture :

- When a pawn moves two rows forward, let it be split into two pawns. The "real" pawn which moves two rows and has its regular color (yellow or brown), and a "ghost" pawn which moves only one row and has a different color (light yellow or light brown).
- After the yellow player makes their move, clear all light brown pawns from the board (and do the same for light yellow pawns after the brown player's move).
- In isTargetLocationFree(), ignore light yellow and light brown pawns.
- In isTargetLocationCaptureable(), if the Target piece is yellow pawn, return true if the target location's piece is either brown or light brown. Otherwise, return true only if the target location's piece is brown. Do similar check for brown piece.
- Finally, if the pawn captures a "ghost" pawn, make sure to remove the corresponding "real" pawn from the board.